# Lagrange nodal basis proof.

Tags: numerical-methods

$\text{Let } L_{n,i}, i = 0,...,n, \text{be the Lagrange nodal basis at} x_0 < x_1<...<x_n$. Show that, for any polynomial $q \in P_n$

$$\sum_{i=0}^nq(x_i)L_{n,i}(x)= q(x)$$

also

If $ p_n \in P_n$ interpolates $f$ at $x_0 < x_1< x_2<...< x_n$ and $q \in P_n$, prove that $p_n + q$ interpolates $f+ q$ at $x_0 < x_1< x_2<...< x_n$

I don't even know where to start, we have a terrible numerical analysis lecturer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define the lagrange basis again. It is given for $n+1$ data points $x_i, i=0,...,n$ by

$L_{n,i}(x) = \prod_{j=0,j\not=i}^n\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}$.

NOTE: You have $n+1$ elements in your Lagrange basis.

The lagrange basis is just constructed in a way, such that $L_{n,i}(x_j) = \delta_{i,j}$ (**check that always one factor vanishes so the product is zero for $x_j\not=x_i$ in the definition of $L_{n,i}(x)$**).

Therefore when evaluating your Left-hand side from above (the sum) at some $x_i$ you get

$\sum_{j=0}^n q(x_j)L_{n,j}(x_i) = q(x_1)L_{n,1}(x_i) + ... + q(x_n)L_{n,n}(x_i)$.

Using the fact stated above, that $L_{n,m}(x_k) = \delta_{m,k}$ you see that all terms of this sum EXCEPT ONE vanish. Therefore the sum gets

$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{j=0}^n q(x_j)L_{n,j}(x_i) &=& q(x_1)L_{n,1}(x_i) + ... + q(x_n)L_{n,n}(x_i) \\ &=& q(x_1)\delta_{1,i}+q(x_2)\delta_{2,i} + ... + q(x_n)\delta_{n,i} \\ &=& q(x_i)\delta_{i,i} \\ &=& q(x_i)
\end{eqnarray}$

By doing this in each point $x_0,...,x_n$ you get $n+1$ function-values of a polynomial of degree $n$ (**Do you see that the degree of the left-hand side is n?**)

Now you should have shown somewhere before in the lecture, that a polynomial of degree $k$ is uniquely determined by $k+1$ conditions (i.e. the number of unknowns in the polynomial). Hence, the left hand side must be equal to $q(x)$, as it coincides at $n+1$ points with $q$, which again is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Can you do the rest? (The idea is very similar...)

EDIT: 
Claim: a polynomial $p$ of order $n$ is uniquely defined by its values at $n+1$ points.

Proof: you can do this in several ways. One way would be to do the following: a general polynomial of degree $n$, so especially $p$, is of the form

$p(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_{n}x^n$.

If you have given the value of $p$ at $n+1$ points $x_0,...,x_n$, this means

$p(x_i) = a_0 + a_1x_i+...+a_nx_i^n = f_i,\,i=1,...,n+1$.

If you write this down in a matrix this means

$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1&x_1&x_1^2&...&x_1^n\\1&x_2&x_2^2&...&x_2^n\\...&...&...&...&...\\1&x_n&x_n^2&...&x_n^n\end{bmatrix}}_{V}\begin{bmatrix}a_0\\a_1\\...\\a_{n}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}f_0\\f_2\\...\\f_{n}\end{bmatrix}$

The matrix $V$ in this system is called the Vandermonde-Matrix.
It's determinant can be calculated as

$det(V) = \prod_{0\leq i < j\leq n} (x_j-x_i)$

You see: the determinant does not vanish (that means the system is uniquely solvable) if and only if all points $x_i$ for the interpolation are different from each other, that is $x_i\not=x_j,\,i\not=j$.

Comment: First, why did you choose to use $n$ data points instead of $n+1$?

Comment: $L_{n,i}(x) = \prod_{j=1,j\not=i}^n\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry about the multiple comments, but I has this first of all but I didn't feel as thought it was correct. Could you explain a little better please.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! You're right, I had some typos in it. It depends somehow on your convention: you may always address your grid points like $x_0,...,x_n$ (that is $n+1$ points), or you may start with $x_1$ (just $n$ points). 

I mixed both conventions, but corrected the index-errors in my answer above. This makes $L_{n,i}$ a polynomial of degree $n$.

Does this solve your questions?
Let me know :-)

Comment: In that case, I had this down! but I thought I was writing down rubbish :( I could not reason why the polynomial is given by it though ( we have never shown this is lecture, the part about a polynomial of degree k being determined by k+1 points) :(. Would the second part be something along the lines of $p_n(x_i) + q(x_i) = f(x_i) + q(x_i) =( f+q)(x_i) \forall i \in [0,n] $ by the reason that a polynomial of degree $k$ is uniquely determined by $k+1$ points ?

Comment: Okay I already imagined that. In numerics you usually have 2 types of proves: firstly there are strange looking claims that are clear, if you just write down what you know from definitions etc. and secondly just proves that work if you know how to chose e.g. Sequences s.t in the end it works out. This problem is of the first type. :D I'm gonna Add something to the first answer, check it out.

Comment: And yes, your approach for the second part is right! :)

Comment: Denis, you have been a great help!

Comment: I'm goas to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

Let me propose one more method of proof.
"[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", section "Lagrange interpolation", describes a determinant form of Lagrange polynomial that interpolates $(x_0;y_0)$, $\dots$, $(x_n;y_n)$
$$
P(x) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0       & y_0       & y_1       & \cdots & y_n       \\
        x^n     & x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x^{n-1} & x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots  & \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1       & 1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$
Obviously, setting all $y_i = q(x_i)$ we'll get the expression you need, because
$$
    P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n\, y_i L_i(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n q(x_i) L_i(x).
$$
So I just plug them in
$$
P(x) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0       & q(x_0)    & q(x_1)    & \cdots & q(x_n)    \\
        x^n     & x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x^{n-1} & x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots  & \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1       & 1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}
$$
Now consider the fact that if the degree of $q(x_i)$ is less then of equal to $n$, I can write it as a linear combination of $1$, $x_i$, $\dots$, $x_i^n$ that reside in the same column
$$
    q(x_i) = a_0 + a_1 x_i + \dots + a_n x_i^n.
$$
Thus I subtract from the first row of the matrix in the numerator all the rest rows with appropriate coefficients (e.g. $a_n$ for the row containing $n$-th powers of $x$).
As a result we will get
$$
P(x) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        -q(x)   & 0         & 0         & \cdots &   0       \\
        x^n     & x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x^{n-1} & x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots  & \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1       & 1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$
Laplace expansion along the first row leads to
$$
P(x) = q(x)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
} = q(x).
$$
For practical example you may want to check "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", section "Lagrange interpolation".